# I am getting empty list in windows 7 while in ubuntu it works correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am scraping a site using beautifulsoup4.

The below code is running well in ubuntu but in windows the second print does not work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
from urlparse import urljoin


baseurl = "http://www.testsite.com"
url = urllib2.urlopen(baseurl)
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a")

print links

region_urls = []
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'width':'100%'} ):
    links = table.findAll('a')
    for link in links:
        region_urls.append(urljoin(baseurl, link["href"]))

print region_urls
```

The first print is working correctly in windows 7 but second print returns empty list.

I am totally confused.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the html as well it's really hard to say anything. Either way the first links you gather, nothing is done with them. You overwrite them inside the for loop, so unless there's links inside the tables; the code won't return anything for the second print.

Comment: The HTML is perfect... I am getting same HTML in ubuntu and windows... Only second print does not work.... I am absolutely sure about the HTML.

Comment: What if you switch from `html.parser` to `lxml` or `html5lib`? What if you switch from `urllib2` to `requests`? Same problem?

Comment: I switched to lxml and it worked!!
Thanks..